# How to resolve the issue while importing a module?

Tags: python, data-science

Below is my folder structure.

```
My_Project
|
+-- Project
     |
     +-- file1.py
     |    
     +-- folder1.py
       |  
       +-- folder2.py
           |
           +--file2.py
```

Can anyone help me with how to import the file1.py in file2.py as a module?

Till now, I've tried using something like this which doesn't work:

from Project.file1 import some_function which returned No module named 'Project'

I have also tried:

`from ...file1 import some_function`

This returned, attempted relative import with no parent package.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21788/how-does-editing-work

Comment: Also, have you added an empty `__init__.py` file in the folder you're importing from?

Comment: Yes I have indeed added an empty __init__.py file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this answer by Cameron:

> By default, you can't. When importing a file, Python only searches the current directory, the directory that the entry-point script is running from, and sys.path which includes locations such as the package installation directory (it's actually a little more complex than this, but this covers most cases).

> However, you can add to the Python path at runtime:

```
# some_file.py
import sys
# insert at 1, 0 is the script path (or '' in REPL)
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```

Edit: I later found this answer by joey:

> Nothing wrong with:

> `from application.app.folder.file import func_name`

> Just make sure folder also contains an **init**.py, this allows it to be included as a package. Not sure why the other answers talk about PYTHONPATH.

Comment: I have just edited the question. I did not use the .py extension while importing.

Comment: I have actually added the __init__.py files, but let me try and get back to you.

Comment: The init files were there, but the sys.path.insert worked. Thanks @Micara